# Scroll list with fixed position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

I use pagePiling.js and i want ja navbar for sections. See the example picture. If i scroll down, want that the entry 3 jump in the place of entry 2 and entry 4 comes from bottom. Thanks

[image: click here for example]

is that a css or jquery trick?

Comment: Because you want it to "jump" and replace, that's jQuery. There's a bunch of tutorials on effects like these online. Cheers !

Comment: @DennisNovac Thank you. Do u have an example link? I don't know what to google. lol :)

Comment: Try search for "scrolling list jquery" --> https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/ See the infinite numbers scrolling.